# MySQL replication 'connecting to master'

Tags: mysql, replication, windows

Anyone please give detailed documentation on MySQL Replication on Windows system. I replicated master to slave, but it is showing 'connecting to master'. Error number showing as 1045 and 2003 it's varying.

Answer (score 1):

If you have validated the credentials you are using for replication and they work connecting through another client, your 1045 error may lie with the [new default authentication plugin in MySQL8](https://lefred.be/content/mysql-8-0-more-about-new-authentication-plugin-and-replication/). When trying to connect with an insecure connection and an account created with the caching_sha2_password, it will continuously attempt the connection without being successful.

Try connecting using the same replication credentials from the slave to the master through a MySQL client. This will ensure your networking and credentials are both valid. If you cannot do this, check your network/firewall and your replication credentials.

Answer (score 0):

1045 probably means that the `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ..` (on the master) does not agree with the user/password given in `CHANGE MASTER` when setting up replication.

2003 is either a fall out of the above problem, or a hardware or firewall problem in the network.